# Why isnt this JS adding data into the div when I choose a drop down option?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Everytime I choose a drop down option instead of displaying the data retrieved from MySQL through AJAX it displays undefined instead if I place the showUser under window load and if I place Showuser outside of window load it says Uncaught ReferenceError: showUser is not defined.

Says showUser undefined:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[ 
  window.addEvent('load', function() {
  document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = "";

var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage["numbers"] || "[]");
localStorage.clear()
    saved.length = 0;





};

function bindName() {
    var inputNames = document.getElementById("names").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
        inputNames[i].onkeydown = function() {
            if (this.value == "") {
                setTimeout(deletename(this), 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}





function deletename(name) {
    if (name.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("names").removeChild(name);
    }
}



//one function
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var myString = xmlhttp.responseText;

var mySplitResult = myString.split("*");


    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML+=mySplitResult[1];


        var num1 = mySplitResult[1];



    var itemsToTest = num1.value;





        var form1 = document.getElementById("names");

        var nameOfnames = form1.getElementsByClassName("inputNames").length;

        var newGuy1 = document.createElement("input");

        newGuy1.setAttribute("class", "inputNames");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("id", nameOfnames);
        newGuy1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("value", num1.value);



        form1.appendChild(newGuy1);
        num1.value = "";
        bindName();

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
  });
  //]]>



  </script>
```

HTML:

```
 <h1>Enter Name</h1>
<div id="mainName">
    <h2>name</h2>
    <label for="name">Add Names: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <button id="addName">Add</button>
     <button id="reset" class="formbuttonReset">Reset</button>
    <form>
        <div id="names">

        </div>
        <input METHOD="POST" action="text.php" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>





<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Achau</option>
<option value="2">Ravi</option>
<option value="3">Justin</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />


<div id="txtHint">
<b><table>
<tr>
<th>Email: <div id="email"></div></th>
<th>Number: <div id="number"></div></th>


</tr></b></div>
```

However if I move the show user outside of window on load function it adds undefined to div:

[image]

PVG I put the showUser into window.onload's scope and did what you said and when I choose an option from drop down nothing happens and I get JS error showUser not defined...
EDIT:

```
 //<![CDATA[ 
  window.addEvent('load', function() {
  document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = "";

var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage["numbers"] || "[]");
localStorage.clear()
    saved.length = 0;





};

//one function
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var myString = xmlhttp.responseText;

var mySplitResult = myString.split("*");


    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML+=mySplitResult[1];


        var num1 = mySplitResult[1];



    var itemsToTest = num1.value;





        var form1 = document.getElementById("names");

        var nameOfnames = form1.getElementsByClassName("inputNames").length;

        var newGuy1 = document.createElement("input");

        newGuy1.setAttribute("class", "inputNames");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("id", nameOfnames);
        newGuy1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("value", num1.value);



        form1.appendChild(newGuy1);
        num1.value = "";
        bindName(this.value);

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}


function bindName(name){
    var inputNames = document.getElementById("names").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
        inputNames[i].onkeydown = function() {
            if (name == "") {
                setTimeout(deletename(this), 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}





function deletename(name) {
    if (name.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("names").removeChild(name);
    }
}




  });
  //]]>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't save yourself some work and use jQuery?

Comment: I am new to JS using JQuery Ill confuse myself even more...

Comment: It's good ambition to want to write pure JavaScript. Using a JS framework without knowing pure JavaScript it like flying an aeroplane on autopilot without knowing how to steer the damn thing (I'm exaggerating, of course). On the other hand, frameworks are extremely useful and provide a nice layer of cross-browseryness. :-)

Comment: "Pure JavaScript"? Better call it "pure DOM with browser-specific differences" - nothing related to the *language* JavaScript. So even as a beginner you'll have it easier for sure when using jQuery. And since jQuery is rather new compared to pure DOM/JS, chances are good you don't find those extremely horrible pieces of example code you are likely to find for plain JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify `bindNames()` to accept a parameter `name` and use it instead of `this.value`. Like so:

```
function bindNames(name) {
    // ..
    if (name == "") {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And from `showUser()`, you'll have to call pass along the parameter, like this:

```
bindNames(this.value);
```

**Edit**: I've taken another look at your code and I must admit I find it hard to figure out what you're trying to do, partly because you haven't really told us and partly because some of the code just doesn't make *any* sense. Things like this:

```
var nameOfnames = form1.getElementsByClassName("inputNames").length;
```

I haven't got a clue what you're trying to do! Do you know? Do you remember what you were trying to do when you wrote this?

Anyway, I've stripped down the problem to the bare minimum. **Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/jNkR3/3/**

It probably doesn't do what you want **at all**, but have a look at it anyway. See if you can follow it and take it from there. Don't add things like XHR and localStorage until you're *certain* the core functionality is working as it should.

Also, it really helps (for yourself) to keep your code readable. One effective way of doing this is to keep your code **short**. If you notice that you need 5 lines of code to do one "thing", it's time to stop and think. Can you describe in a few words what those 5 lines are doing? If so: make a function out of it! You'll have replaced 5 lines of code with *one* function call, which makes the code much easier to read.

If you need any more help, you're better off posting your problem on a forum. Stack Overflow really isn't meant for long discussions.

Answer (score 0):

`showUser` is defined only in context of `window.addEvent('load', function() {`. You either need to move it to global scope or need to change it's definition to something like:

```
window.showUser = function (str)
{
//...
}
```

And BTW format your code with tabs it will save you a lot of trouble.

**EDIT**: Haven't noticed the other part of the question - myString.split("*") probably isn't working as you expect but what you really should do is add a `debugger;` keyword and debug with Firebug (for Firefox) or built in debugger for others.

**EDIT**: Having a third look PPvG is also right but I would simply change `bindName();` to `bindName.call(this);`.

**EDIT**: I'm wondering when you will admit that you made this code like that on purpose ;-). But seriously I think this line is the problem with undefined thing: `var itemsToTest = num1.value;` + the other `num1.value`. You need to get to know some JS debugger to trace things like that and really format and plan your code better.

Comment: I believe he had already noticed that: **"[...] if I move [showUser] outside of window on load function it adds undefined to div"**.

Comment: And it doesn't matter whether you use tabs or spaces, as long as you have a decent editor (vim, emacs, whatever) and minimize your JS before going to production.

Comment: The point with tabs was to use correct indentation for blocks of code. I don't mean to go over a dispute of tabs vs spaces ;-).

Comment: I dontk now what to do its one error after another after I add "window.showUser = function (str)" to showUser now I get the error BindName is not defined. If i add "window.BindName = function (name)" to BindName function I dont get any error but in the div undefined gets added...

Comment: why do you think itemsToTest is the problem? its not doing anything in the code...not affecting it in any way

Comment: I meant the num1.value thing. You can't have num1.value in any case after a call to split() on a string.